# Can update factory from controller but not from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a Modal module that can be called from anywhere in the app but I've come across a problem that probably highlights a misunderstanding on my part but I can't see what it is.

Heres a jsFiddle of what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/dwSX8/2/

When I update the ModalAPI from the controller everything works as expected, but when I do the same from a directive nothing.

So my HTML is:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <button ng-click="logout()">Via Controller</button>
        <button logout>Via Directive</button>
    </div>
    <modal></modal>
</div>
```

and my Angular JS stuff:

```
angular.module('Modal', [])
.factory('ModalAPI', function () {

    return {
        title: 'Before click',             
        open: function(title){
            console.log('new title: ' + title);
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
})

.directive('modal', function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        replace:true,
        controller: function($scope, ModalAPI){

            $scope.m = ModalAPI;

            $scope.$watch('modal.title', toggle);

            function toggle() {
                console.log(' ---------- Modal changed!!!!');
            };
        },
        template: '<div>{{m.title}}</div>'
    };
})

angular.module('app', ['Modal'])
.controller('AppCtrl',  function ($scope, ModalAPI) {
    $scope.logout = function(){
         console.log('clicked');
         ModalAPI.open('After controller click')
    }
})
.directive('logout', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, element, ModalAPI) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
                ModalAPI.open('After directive click')
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bind event is outside of Angular's scope. **Angular doesn't know that the event has been fired**.

Therefore, you have to wrap your call in an $apply function:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  element.bind('click', function(){
    ModalAPI.open('After directive click')
  })
});
```

Further reading: [$scope](http://goo.gl/7rOaX)

Comment: Thanks, combined with Eddiec answer I've got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You should inject your services where you declare your directive, not in the link function. The third parameter in a link function are the element's attributes.

```
.directive('logout', function(ModalAPI){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
                ModalAPI.open('After directive click')
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You were both right, plus I also restricted the logout to 'E' rather than 'A', so triple wrong! I accepted Sprottenwels as they answered first but yours was equally helpful. Thanks!