# Update factory from controller works but not from directive

Tags: controller, factory, directive

Im new to angular and have a simmilar problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541326/can-update-factory-from-controller-but-not-from-directive), but the solution does not work for me.

I use two controllers wich have access to the factory, if up update the factory value the two controllers also update their values.

But if i use a directive to update the factory value the controlles will not update.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('testFactory', function () {
    var countF = 1;
    return {
        getCount: function () {

            return countF;
        },
        incrementCount: function () {
            countF++;
            return countF;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('FactoryCtrl',function($scope,testFactory){
    $scope.countFactory = testFactory.getCount;
    $scope.clickF = function () {
        $scope.countF = testFactory.incrementCount();
    };
});

app.controller('anotherCtrl',function($scope, testFactory) {
    $scope.countFactory = testFactory.getCount;
    $scope.clickF = function () {
        $scope.countF = testFactory.incrementCount();
    };
});

app.directive("d1", function (testFactory) {

    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    element.bind('click', function () {
                        testFactory.incrementCount();
                    })
                });
        }
    };
});
```

[See in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuUHS/217/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

```
app.directive("d1", function (testFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        scope: false,
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                testFactory.incrementCount();
                $scope.$apply();
            });

        }
    };
});
```